# How to handle null Request Tags in wso2 BPS

Tags: wso2, bpel

I have created a service in wso2 BPS. Now while i am testing my service i have come accross a problem. That is my request payload is like :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:roms="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <roms:CreateSceduler>
         <roms:SampleID>?</roms:SampleID>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <roms:ScheduleID>?</roms:ScheduleID>
         <roms:PersonID>?</roms:PersonID>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <roms:PersonName>?</roms:PersonName>
         <roms:Location>?</roms:Location>
         <roms:CreatedDateUTC>?</roms:CreatedDateUTC>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <roms:RecordDateTimeUTC>?</roms:RecordDateTimeUTC>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <roms:RecordedBy>?</roms:RecordedBy>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <roms:RecordedAt>?</roms:RecordedAt>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <roms:LastModifiedBy>?</roms:LastModifiedBy>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <roms:LastModifiedDateUTC>?</roms:LastModifiedDateUTC>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <roms:LastModifiedAt>?</roms:LastModifiedAt>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <roms:Comments>?</roms:Comments>
      </roms:CreateRoundTask>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now as seen above, there are optional as well as mandatory tags. 
Now my boss wants that while i am trying to hit the service in soap ui i will not pass the optional tags and will only pass the mandatory ones like :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:roms="http://tempuri.org/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <roms:CreateSceduler>
             <roms:SampleID>?</roms:SampleID>
             <roms:PersonID>?</roms:PersonID>
             <roms:Location>?</roms:Location>
             <roms:CreatedDateUTC>?</roms:CreatedDateUTC>
             </roms:CreateRoundTask>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>

But when i invoke my BPS service with this payload in soap ui i get selection failure fault.
How can i achieve above functionality which my boss wants in wso2 BPS. 
Looking forward to your answers. Thanks in advance
```

Comment: Let's assume `<roms:Comments>` is an optional field.  Q: Are you passing an empty item (`<roms:Comments></roms:Comments>`) or are you passing NOTHING (just not sending any `<roms:Comments>` tag at all)?  If you "don't want to send optional fields", I would strongly recommend the latter.  IMHO...

Comment: No we are not passing the element i.e. i am not sending any <roms:Comments> tag at all

Comment: I used "roms:Comments" as an example. Q: For the field(s) in question, are you sending "empty" tags (bad) or NOTHING (good)?

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:roms="http://tempuri.org/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <roms:CreateSceduler>
             <roms:SampleID>?</roms:SampleID>
             <roms:PersonID>?</roms:PersonID>
             <roms:Location>?</roms:Location>
             <roms:CreatedDateUTC>?</roms:CreatedDateUTC>
             </roms:CreateRoundTask>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
This is my request with which i am invoking my service, and have removed the optional tags. So i am sending nothing

Comment: OK: then you'll have to debug from the server side.  Maybe the server doesn't consider them "optional", and maybe it expects to see the "missing fields".  Or maybe the problem is something else altogether (you aren't really sending "?", are you?).  In any case: look at the server logs, debug the problem from the server side.  Good luck!

Comment: Actually that is my question. I want to know how can i handle above situation

Comment: Q: You know that you're supposed to type in valid data where SoapUI puts "?" in a sample SOAP message, don't you?

Comment: The error i.e selection failure that i am getting is not due to data but due to the missing tags. And thsu i want to handle this error in BPS itself

Answer (score 1):

A BPEL selection failure means that your BPEL process tries to access an element on your message that is not there.

If this selection failure happens in an `<assign>` activity, you can set the `ignoreMissingFromData` attribute in the `<copy>` element in order to ignore such cases. See the BPEL spec, page 63:

> The optional ignoreMissingFromData attribute of the  construct is used to specify
>   whether a bpel:selectionFailure standard fault is suppressed as specified in section 8.4.1. 
>   Selection Result of Copy Operations. The default value of the ignoreMissingFromData is "no".

If the selection failure happens in a condition, you'd need to check for the existence of this element first.